# Getting a "cannot find the file specified" while running a MSTest

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mstest

I'm going through a Lynda training course on Azure APIs. The instructor is doing some unit tests using MSTest. I've followed his code, but am getting the following error:

> Test Name:    CustomerGetAllTest Test
>   FullName: H_Plus_Sports.Tests.CustomerIntegrationTests.CustomerGetAllTest
>   Test
>   Source:   I:\ScratchSrc\H_Plus_Sports\H_Plus_Sports.Tests\CustomerIntegrationTests.cs
>   : line 21 Test Outcome:   Failed Test Duration:   0:00:00.2810103
>
> Result StackTrace:     at
>   H_Plus_Sports.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection
>   services)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.Initialize()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.TestServer..ctor(IWebHostBuilder
>   builder, IFeatureCollection featureCollection)    at
>   H_Plus_Sports.Tests.CustomerIntegrationTests..ctor() in
>   I:\ScratchSrc\H_Plus_Sports\H_Plus_Sports.Tests\CustomerIntegrationTests.cs:line
>   16 Result Message:    Unable to create instance of class
>   H_Plus_Sports.Tests.CustomerIntegrationTests. Error:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc, Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file
>   specified..

I don't understand why I'm getting the complaint about MSTest not being able to find the Microsoft.AspNetCode.Mvc file.

Comment: Maybe the user the test runs under lacks the rights to access the folder? Maybe you did not copy that file to the output directory/test directoy?

Comment: Rui, thank you very much for giving me that link. That did resolve the problem. I tried searching using the keywords, but I must not have used the right ones, because I didn't find that link. Thanks again, this solves my problem.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Few possible problems:
Try running program as administrator.
Make sure the path is correct or the file is there.

Issue with relative/absolute path, sometimes the program will take a relative path and think that the path you provided is within the solution directory.

Comment: Katada and Christopher, thank you for suggesting the possibility of not having the necessary permissions. That might be the problem, but I'm not sure. And unfortunately, I can't test it. I'm working a laptop with limited disk space, so I put the projects onto a network share. I just tried running VS 2017 as Administrator. I will not open any project on the network share; VS doesn't see the network share. And I haven't enough room on my laptop's HD for projects.